# Multiple Applescript lines from terminal osascript call

Tags: applescript, osascript

So I'm trying to run multiple Applescript commands from the command line in one go. However, no matter how I try it, it won't work:

```sh
$ osascript -e "set x to 0; display dialog x"
$ osascript -e "set x to 0 \n display dialog x"
$ osascript -e "set x to 0 then display dialog x"
```

Is there a way to do this without saving to file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
osascript -e "set x to 0" -e "display dialog x"
```

Have a look at the `-e` *option* in the *manual page* for `osascript` in **Terminal**: `man osascript`

> **−e** *statement*
> Enter one line of a script. If **−e** is given, **osascript** will not look for a filename in the argument list. Multiple **−e** options may be given to build up a multi-line script. Because most scripts use char- acters that are special to many shell programs (for example, AppleScript uses single and double quote marks, “(”, “)”, and “∗”), the statement will have to be correctly quoted and escaped to get it past the shell intact.

You can also do e.g.:

```
osascript <<END         
set x to 0       
display dialog x
END
```

Or:

```
osascript -e '          
set x to 0
display dialog x'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second attempt was very close to proper:

```
osascript -e "set x to 0 
PRESS ENTER
display dialog x"
PRESS ENTER
```